# How to delete a document attribute in Sanity iO?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sanity

I have an array of objects in my Sanity Document called Images called Comments

an example comment object in comments[] array looks like :

```
    {
    "_key": "6510dc79cf8b",
    "comment": "Hello world",
    "postedBy": {
        "_id": "117108441389496202965",
        "image": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Ggq3iKH-nketDY9Qx7Y2Yva09E5_2WNJYVr77AA9AQ=s96-c",
        "userName": "haha"
    }
  }
```

I want to delete this comment in the comments array which exists in the Images document.

In my Image schema Sanity looks like :

```
      {
      name: "comments",
      title: "Comments",
      type: "array",
      of: [{ type: "comment" }],
    },
  ],
};
```

I'm trying to delete this comment by

```
    const deleteComment = async (key) => {
    try {
      client
      .patch(pinId)
      .delete([{ comment, _key: key, postedBy: { _type: "postedBy", _ref: user._id } }])
      .commit()
      .then(() => {
        fetchPinDetails();
        setComment("");
        setAddingComment(false);
      });
      window.location.reload();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

But delete() doesnt exist on patch.

IS there another way to do this simple query (if it was in SQL)? Driving me nuts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do it using [unset](https://www.sanity.io/docs/http-patches#xRtBjp8o). Something like this:

```js
client.patch(pinId).unset([`comments[_key==${key}]`]).commit()
```

Comment: I kept running into an error until I put the key into double quotes like this  `.unset([`comments[_key=="${key}"]`])`

Comment: Excellent tip @Shasa putting the key in quotes worked for me as well!